# How Do I Fix A Flexbox Sticky Footer In IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox, sticky-footer

I have created a sticky footer using flexbox. It works in all browsers apart from IE11.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/Pedr/pen/doaWeq)

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.Page {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.Page-header {
  background: blue;
}

.Page-footer {
  background: green;
}

.Page-body {
  background: red;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="Page">
  <header class="Page-header">
    HEADER
  </header>
  <div class="Page-body">
    BODY
  </div>
  <footer class="Page-footer">
    FOOTER
  </footer>
</div>
```

**Why is it breaking in IE11 and how can I fix it?**

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try

```
flex: 1 0 auto;
```

for content block

Comment: Odd. For me it does not work in IE11. The body/content just gets the height of a single line of text.

Comment: After some tinkering it does appear to work when I also add `body { display: flex }`. Not sure why.

Comment: @ACJ I'm kind of late to the party, but the **flex** property only work for elements which use the **flex** display. The flexbox mechanism introduces a lot of cool features. You can check them out [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: @IonuțCiuta, my point was more subtle. The OP already sets flex display to the container (`.Page`). However, I could only achieve the desired result if I *also* apply flex display to the `body`, which seems unrelated. My best guess is that this is an artifact of the specific way the IE11 rendering engine handles the flex model.

Comment: Holy moly. Came here 2 years later. Have been trying to fix flexbox in IE7 for weeks now and this is finally the solution I've been looking for. Thanks!

Comment: For me, in a slightly different situation, I had to do this along with the suggestion made by @nacht-reinstate-monica and change min-height to height on my page container. Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

The problem is that in IE11 flexbox won't honour `min-height`, so the flex box collapses to the height of its contents.

You can fix it by wrapping your flexbox inside another flexbox that also has `flex-direction: column`. You will also need to set `flex: 1` on your original flexbox. For some reason this forces the nested flexbox to honour any its `min-height`.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/Pedr/pen/vObmWV)

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.Wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Page {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.Page-header {
  background: blue;
}

.Page-footer {
  background: green;
}

.Page-body {
  background: red;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="Wrapper">
  <div class="Page">
    <header class="Page-header">
      HEADER
    </header>
    <div class="Page-body">
      BODY
    </div>
    <footer class="Page-footer">
      FOOTER
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work good in IE11 when content of `.Page-body` gets bigger then it's parent height: [codepen](http://codepen.io/cakeseller/pen/xOopLk)

Comment: @Cake_Seller, did you solve this issue when inner content gets bigger than the parent container?

Comment: @ArtyomPranovich nope, unfortunately not.

Comment: I added those styles to the `body { display: flex; width: 100%; flex-direction: column; }` (my body only contains a single `div#app`, as many webapps do and which has the same role like above `.Page`) and things appear to be fine in IE11, Edge and Windows Chrome. Short and Long pages.

Comment: Instead of flex: 1 on .Page-body, do flex-grow:1 and flex-shrink: 0. That does it for me.

Answer (score 4):

I got around it using [flexbug's recommendation of changing `min-height` on the body to just `height`](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-3)

Only works for certain circumstances, sticky footers seem to be one of the common use cases.